# Twitter API V2 403: Forbidden using tweepy in python

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I have had issue with Twitter API V2 403: Forbidden using tweepy

```py
import tweepy
    consumer_key= 'XX1'
    consumer_secret= 'XX2'
    access_token= 'XX3'
    access_token_secret= 'XX4'
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    api.update_status("Hello Tweepy")
```

i'm getting error :Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
453 - You currently have Essential access which includes access to Twitter API v2 endpoints only. If you need access to this endpoint, you’ll need to apply for Elevated access via the Developer Portal. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/about-twitter-api#v2-access-leve

And i changed my code like this than it works

```py
import tweepy
client = tweepy.Client(consumer_key="",
                    consumer_secret="",
                    access_token="",
                    access_token_secret="")
# Replace the text with whatever you want to Tweet about
response = client.create_tweet(text='hello world')
```

Can i post tweet with text and media using this methon
Is there any way post tweet with media like this method